# Variable declared and not used in conditional statement

Tags: go, scope

I declare some variables (`offsetI` and `limitI`) outside of a conditional statement.  Inside the conditional statement I am trying to assign them values, then use those values for a query after the conditional statement.

```
var (
    number, size, offset, limit string
    offsetI, limitI             uint64
)

// Get the string values for number, size, offset, and limit
// ...

if size != "" {

    // Parse the number value
    numberI, err := strconv.ParseUint(number, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {...}

    // Parse the size value
    limitI, err = strconv.ParseUint(size, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {...}

    // Calculate the offset
    offsetI = numberI * limitI

} else {

    // Parse the limit value
    limitI, err := strconv.ParseUint(limit, 10, 64)         // limitI declared and not used
    if err != nil {...}

    // Parse the offset value
    offsetI, err = strconv.ParseUint(offset, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {...}
}

// Make the query using offsetI and limitI
result, err := s.GetAllPaginated(offsetI, limitI)
if err != nil {...}
```

---

I am not intending to re-declare the `limitI` variable in the scope of the `else` statement, but I need to use the `:=` operator for declaring a new `err` variable.

The only thing I could come up with was to separately declare another `err` variable, so I could use a regular assignment statement:

```
} else {

    var err error    // New

    // Regular assignment statement now
    limitI, err = strconv.ParseUint(limit, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {...}
```

---

I would like to be able to do this without having to declare an additional error variable.

Comment: It's awkward, but yes, that's exactly what you have to do. `:=` with multiple vars on the left will redeclare _all_ of them that weren't already declared in the same scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra `var error` is awkward, but it's a common way to address this situation. [The spec on scoping](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) says (emphasis mine):

> The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the *innermost containing block*.

So in your case, that short variable declaration is declaring a *different* `limitI` scoped to the "innermost containing block." Since it only "lives" until the next closing brace, it isn't used.

In your specific case, an option might be to declare `err` outside the if/else, since it's used in both inner scopes, so you can use use `=` instead of `:=` with those functions returning `error`s.  Then there's no "inner `limitI`" declared and you have no unused variable issue.

"Shadowing" situations like this can also produce unexpected behavior rather than an error. `go vet -shadow` [tries to detect "[v]ariables that may have been unintentionally shadowed"](https://golang.org/cmd/vet/#hdr-Shadowed_variables) and, different but related, [gordonklaus/ineffasign](https://github.com/gordonklaus/ineffassign) generalizes the "unused variable" check to detect useless assignments even if they weren't declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing I could come up with was to separately declare another err variable

This is being studied in the context of a future Go 2 (2019? 2020).
See "[Error Handling — Problem Overview](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-error-handling-overview.md)" (Russ Cox - August 27, 2018)

A possible proposed new syntax would avoid having to redeclare err:

Example:

```
func CopyFile(src, dst string) error {
    handle err {
        return fmt.Errorf("copy %s %s: %v", src, dst, err)
    }

    r := check os.Open(src)
    defer r.Close()

    w := check os.Create(dst)
    handle err {
        w.Close()
        os.Remove(dst) // (only if a check fails)
    }

    check io.Copy(w, r)
    check w.Close()
    return nil
}
```

---

Note that `go vet -shadow` is no longer available [since Go 1.12](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#vet) (February 2019):

> The experimental `-shadow` option is no longer available with `go vet`.
>   Checking for variable shadowing may now be done using
>
> ```
> go install golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/shadow/cmd/shadow
> go vet -vettool=$(which shadow)
> ```